# 'startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)' is deprecated. How shall i fix this error

Tags: deprecated, startactivityforresult

```
private void openGallery() {
    Intent pickImage = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(pickImage, REQ);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQ && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri=data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            noticeImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

I was trying to upload an image from a gallery but its showing nothing when I click on the `UploadImage`. As my code is not being able to fetch the Gallery from my desktop.